# Linking '#define Version x.x' in C with the version tag in Git

Tags: c, git, header

I'm sure people do this already, hence the question. 
In my C project, I define the current version using:

```
#define VERSION 3.2.1
```

This is placed in a global header file and is used for various tasks such as in a UDP packet that tells the user the versions of firmware/software running.

In Git (using git bash) we can assign tags to the commits allowing commits to be referenced by both their hash and this tag. I could just manually use:

```
git checkout <hash>
git tag v3.2.1
```

However, What I'd like is for Git to grab the version variable from the C header file, thus ensuring it is only manually typed once.

I imagine someone has some bash script that does exactly this and can be set up to use a Git alias so that it is handled easily once setup?

Many thanks.
Ed

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `v.h` is the name of the header file with the

```
#define VERSION 3.2.1
```

define.

You can extract the `VERSION` value from it e.g., with

```
version=$(echo VERSION |  c99 -xc -include v.h - -E|tail -n1)
```

and then do

```
git tag v$version
```